# Chromecast Volume Controller on Android 9

Tags: java, android, chromecast

[image]When Chromecast connected , if i use physical button, it appears the Chromecast volume controller beside media volume on Android 8. But does not appear on Android 9. What code i have to add to chromecast integration ?
I want to do like Netflix

Comment: Try to enter this in your address bar: ***chrome://flags/#views-cast-dialog*** then change it from **Default** or **Enabled** to **Disabled**. Once relaunched, it will go to your old UI. Check this forum - [Chromecast volume control disappeared from chrome](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/agrer1/chromecast_volume_control_disappeared_from_chrome/) for more details.

Comment: @jess how can i change on Android ?